# Spring XD Error creating streams with Composite module with shell processor in it

Tags: spring-xd

I have created a composite module:

```
 module compose common-module --definition "kafka --topic=topic1 --outputType=text/plain | shell --command='script1.sh' "
```

I then created a stream using this module:

```
 stream create stream1 --definition "common-module  > queue:job:job1"
```

And I got the following error:

```
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: 
Error with option(s) for module common-module of type source:
command: may not be null
command: may not be empty
```

Anyone knows what's going on?  Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3754).

The only work-around I can think of (short of creating a custom shell module - see the JIRA) is to pass-in the script again...

```
stream create stream1 --definition "common-module --shell.script=script1.sh > queue:job:job1"
```

Comment: Thanks Gary.  So, is this going to be fixed at next SpringXD release ?

Comment: Yes (according to the JIRA issue) but I don't know when that will be. I don't know how easy it will be to fix, I am not familiar with that part of the code base.

Comment: Gary, I have posted a new question regarding SpringXD kafka source module.  Not sure if you have any insight to it.  thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349938/how-to-make-springxd-kafka-source-module-reads-from-where-it-left